# Laravel blade "undefined variable" error when using route()

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

As a project I am building a stackoverflow like forum. On the page on which a single question is shown I want the user to be able to click on the questioner's name and be forwarded to the respective user profile page. I am able to get the name from the database with `{{ $question->user->name }}`. The problem occurs when adding the `<a href=""></a>` part!

Also, the profile pages work. I can access them and the url then says for example: `../profile/1`.

This is the route in the web.php file:

```
Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'PageController@profile')->name('profile');
```

This is the PageController part:

```
public function profile($id)
    {
      $user = User::with(['questions', 'answers', 'answers.question'])->find($id);
      return view('profile')->with('user', $user);
    }
```

This is the code from the show.blade View question page which does not work:

```
<p>
    Submitted by <a href="{{ route('profile', $user->id) }}">{{ $question->user->name }}</a>
</p>
```

The error message I get is `Undefined variable: user`.

Which surprises me because forwarding on the profile page to a specific question works with this blade code:

```
<a href="{{ route('questions.show', $question->id) }}">View Question</a>
```

The respective route in the web.php file:

```
Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionController');
```

And QuestionController:

```
public function show($id)
    {
      $question = Question::findOrFail($id); 

      return view('questions.show')->with('question', $question);
    }
```

I thought I defined the variable `$user` in the PageController like I defined `$question` in the QuestionController?

Comment: I don't see any `$user` in your `QuestionController@show`. User is only in `PageController@profile`

Comment: sometimes using like {{route('questions.show', ['id'=>$question->id]) }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are using Eloquent models with relations. If you want to display the user id on the question, you can use the relation between the `Question` and `User` to find the id of the posting user.

```
Submitted by <a href="{{ route('profile', $question->user->id) }}">{{ $question->user->name }}</a>
                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//just change  your  like this way

 public function profile($id)
{
  $user = User::with(['questions', 'answers', 'answers.question'])->find($id);
  return view('profile',compact('user));
}
```